# Is there a way to import an Excel spreadsheet as a recordset?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database that summarizes and formats personnel data exported from another system as an Excel file.  The current process requires the user to follow the following steps/rules:

1. file must be named `Alpha_Roster.xls*` or `Alpha_Roster.xlsx` and located in the same folder as the database
2. the top two rows must be deleted as to bring the column headers from row 3 to row 1
3. all "excess" columns must be deleted from the Alpha_Roster file as the data in those columns are not used and `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` will fail if they're present

As you can see, this isn't too bad when you're dealing with just a couple of target columns, but we're looking for information from specifically 25 or so columns, and they're mixed in with the excess columns we need to remove (there are 76 columns in the exported file), so it's a rather tedious process to prepare the file for update, which we're having to do weekly.

Once the headers are sorted, the script wipes the data from the AlphaList table, then uses `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "AlphaList", FilePath & "Alpha_Roster", True` to move the new data in.

So with this, I've got a few goals for the update:

1. Remove the whole file name/location bit - *done, using* `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` *and some If statements to check which extension we're pulling in.*
2. Remove the requirement to edit the Access VBA code, should the layout of the exported data change - *considered done, using a loop to pull the fields required by the database to assemble a SQL query to update the database*
3. Remove the requirement to edit the exported Excel file.

And this now brings me to why I'm here - I'm looking for a way to basically pull my Excel file into a temporary recordset or table that I can then run the SQL query against.  Not sure if I can completely get away from removing the top two rows, but just doing that is far better than having to wipe out all of the columns.  I think I'm about there, but everything I'm Googling is coming up just a bit short of the solution I'm looking for.

Here's what I have so far for the test code I'm playing with:

```
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .Title = "Select Alpha Roster File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Open"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Workbook", "*.xls;*.xlsx"
        If .Show = True Then
            SelFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End If
    End With
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=" & SelFile & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes'"
```

Where I'm falling short is how do I get from here to some kind of a recordset that I can run my update query against?  Or can I run my query (`"SELECT " & qryStr & " from ..."`) from here?  Or am I completely on the wrong track here?

As a note, for some reason or another any time I try to define an `ADODB.Recordset` the code checker completely crashes Access, so unfortunately I haven't been able to completely mirror some of the examples I've seen online.

Some things to consider - I'm trying to future proof this just a bit, since I don't know what fields may be added to the exported file.  This is why I'm not just diving straight for `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.  While dumping the entirety of the file into a table with the headers already setup to match what we currently have would be the simplest option, the second something changes in the source file as far as the headers are concerned, the process breaks.  Also, while I may be tech savvy enough to tear the code apart and figure out where things are going sideways, the ultimate end users here... well, let's just say their skill level is pretty basic.  They don't care how it works, just that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the sheet by using SheetName$. (The dollar sign is required)

```
Dim db As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
ExelFileFullPath = "FilePath\filename.xlsx"
db.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & ExelFileFullPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""")
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]"
rs.Open SQL, db, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

Your columns must have headers with Unique names to avoid issues.

Comment: Ok this is just about to where I need it.  Now how would I get the data out of `rs` and into my table?  I have `SQLupd = "INSERT INTO AlphaList " & Iqry & " FROM rst"` where `rst` is the same as `rs` in your example.  I'm then following that with `DoCmd.RunSQL SQLupd` but it says it can't find `rst`.

Comment: There are only two ways, Loop the records found and insert one by one, or save into a file and import the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can *link* the worksheet/range as a table with a single line of code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, ...
```

then use it as any other table, though read-only.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a persistent link though?  I'm only needing the Excel data for the import as all I care about is the latest file that was exported from the other system.

Comment: Well, yes, but just delete it when your task has finished.