# Execute Append Query

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data from VBA excel to Ms Access Database. The data was inserted successfully, the problems are

1. it inserted multiple times. In this case, I only want to insert 3 rows, in the database has 7 rows (1 row for the first record, 2 rows for the second record, and 3 rows for the third record).
2. this query won't work if there is no record in database, so I need to add 1 dummy record make this insert query works.

   ```
   db_path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PWC_Distribution_DB.accdb"
   db_pass = "123abc"
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & 
   db_path & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & db_pass & ";"
   cn.Open
   Set cm = New ADODB.Command
   cm.ActiveConnection = cn
   cm.CommandText = "ins_temp_table"
   cm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("web_tracking", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("incoming_date", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("leads_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("incoming_time", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("leads_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("phone_number", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("email", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("city", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("platform", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("app_date", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("app_time", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("meeting_point", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("agent_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("agent_code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)
   cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("notes", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, 0)

   Do While wsWork.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
      'cm.Parameters.Refresh
       cm.Parameters("web_tracking").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 4)
       cm.Parameters("incoming_date").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 6)
       cm.Parameters("leads_id").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 3)
       cm.Parameters("incoming_time").Value = "10:00"
       cm.Parameters("leads_name").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 10)
       cm.Parameters("phone_number").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 11)
       cm.Parameters("email").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 12)
       cm.Parameters("city").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 13)
       cm.Parameters("platform").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 15)
       cm.Parameters("app_date").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 31)
       cm.Parameters("app_time").Value = "11:00"
       cm.Parameters("meeting_point").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 33)
       cm.Parameters("agent_name").Value = wsWork.Cells(i, 34)
       cm.Parameters("agent_code").Value = "x123"
       cm.Parameters("notes").Value = "x123"
       Set rs = cm.Execute()
       i = i + 1
   Loop
   cn.Close
   ```

[image]

Comment: Show code of stored procedure. You are aware of using a sheet in recordset or link a sheet in access? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026687/is-there-a-way-to-import-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-recordset

Answer (score 2):

Consider an insert-select append query that directly references Excel spreadsheet which is allowable in MS Access SQL. Excel headers are recognized if specified in properties. No loop or dummy rows required.

In below, adjust file and worksheet names in `FROM` clause and columns or constants in `INSERT` and `SELECT`. Then, run inside an MS Access query window which can be saved and run later.

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (web_tracking, incoming_date, leads_id, incoming_time, leads_name,
                     phone_number, email, city, platform, app_date, ap_time, 
                     meeting_point, agent_name, agent_code, notes)
SELECT web_tracking, incoming_date, leads_id, '10:00' AS incoming_time, leads_name,
       phone_number, email, city, platform, app_date, '11:00' AS app_time, 
       meeting_point, agent_name, 'x123' AS agent_code, 'x123' AS notes
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\File.xlsx].[SheetName$]
```

To run a saved query with  ADO:

```vb
...
cn.Open 
cn.Execute "mySavedQuery"
cn.Close
```

Comment: hi, trying your code, but show an error "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only". I already open the database exclusively.

Comment: Can you run the query inside MS Access in query design or by double clicking saved object (not by code)?